# How to fix CSS grid overlapping my navbar?

Tags: html, css

I am a bit new to HTML and CSS. I am not sure how to fix my grids with overlay overlapping my sticky navbar. I created the grid using this method:

```
        <section id="projects">
            <h2>PROJECTS</h2>
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <p><b>Project 1</b></p>
                    <img src="image1.png" alt="image1" class="image1>
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="projects-text">
                            Placeholder
                            <br><a class="repo-text" href="">Repo Link</a> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <p><b>Project 2</b></p>
                    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2" class="image2">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="projects-text">
                            Placeholder
                            <br><a class="repo-text" href="">Repo Link</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-item">
                    <p><b>Project 3</b></p>
                    <img src="image3.jpg" alt="image3" class="image3">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <div class="projects-text">
                            Placeholder
                            <br><a class="repo-text" href="">Repo Link</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

and with this CSS:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    padding: 10px;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid lavender;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: lavender;
}

.grid-item:hover .overlay{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This is my navbar:

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

```
nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

nav li {
    font-family: "";
    float: left;
}

nav a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}

nav a::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 5px;
    transition: width 0.3s ease;
}

nav a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

After commenting out lines of code, I realized the problem was with the `position:relative` in .grid-item, but if I remove it or change the property, the overlaying effect doesn't work anymore. How do I fix this, or is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: What navbar, there is none in the code provided? Please make a [mcve]

Comment: Just added in my code for the navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: fixed` takes the `ul` element out of normal flow, making the header collapse to 0 height and probably hiding it entirely.

Using a flexbox container instead would let you split the page's height into a static header and a body that fills the remaining space.

```css
.layout {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

nav {
  flex: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0002;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
nav li {
  float: left;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 0;
  contain: content;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <nav>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    Page content...
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    ... that may require scrolling
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could just not use `position: fixed` on the `ul`, and give the `header` a `position: sticky; top: 0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS Grid</title>

    <style>
        
        nav {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
            gap: 5px;
        }
 
 
        nav a {
 
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: hsl(60, 56%, 61%);

        }

        nav a:hover {
            background-color: hsl(60, 56%, 81%);
        }


        .grid-item {
            background-color: white;
            border: 5px solid lavender;
            border-radius: 15px;
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 30px;
            text-align: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 350px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .grid-item:hover {
            background-color: beige;
        }








    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <nav>
        <a href="">Link 1</a>
        <a href="">Link 2</a>
        <a href="">Link 3</a>
    </nav>

    <section id="projects">

        <h2>PROJECTS</h2>
        
            <div class="grid-item">
                <p><b>Project 1</b></p>
                <img src="image1.png" alt="image1" class="image1>
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="projects-text">
                        Placeholder
                        <br><a class="repo-text" href="">Repo Link</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="grid-item">
                <p><b>Project 2</b></p>
                <img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2" class="image2">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="projects-text">
                        Placeholder
                        <br><a class="repo-text" href="">Repo Link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="grid-item">
                <p><b>Project 3</b></p>
                <img src="image3.jpg" alt="image3" class="image3">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="projects-text">
                        Placeholder
                        <br><a class="repo-text" href="">Repo Link</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

In fact you need grid only at nav level, if at all you desire to use grid somewhere on your page.